# Excel - SUMIF - Do not return correct value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I am facing a problem with values of...

### What I want

I want the SUM of each UNIQUE key from Other sheet,

I two sheets:

#### Sheet 1 - With Raw Data

| KEY | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 123 |

#### Sheet 2 - Unique Key (where I want to Return the total sum for each unique key)

| KEY (unique) | Total VALUE (sum) for each key |
| --- | --- |
| abc | Total Value |

I have used the this formula:
`=SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A;A2;Sheet1!B:B)`

Using Google Sheets I have the correct value.  But, I do not know why excel returns different values.

### Excel SUMIF vs Excel Pivot Tables Vs Google Sheets:

I have checked by THE SUM of Column VALUE trying:

- **SUMIF**
- and **PIVOT TABLES**

Outputs:

- Google Sheets **Sum If**: 7.686.075,96
- Excel Using **Pivot Tables**: 46.909.880,24
- Excel Using **Sum If** Function:  7.686.075,96

Excel and Google Sheets have different Outputs Using the same data, and the same formulas, Google sheets returns the correct value.

Excel SumIF and Excel Pivot Tables have different Outputs Using the same data Excel Pivot Tables returns the correct value.

[Link For Excel Sheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fNWHvv2IKrTnIIU9vGZp1lKiqPgRUPoY/view?usp=sharing)

[Link for Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NryryJo_tu_zQo4VeHqvCcjeyl4VF1cqy6uItBzfBkA/edit?usp=sharing)

Can anyone give a help here?

Thanks !!!!

Comment: Have you considered formatting the unique key values as text? I'm not 100% sure it will fix it but worth a try perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your keys are long numeric strings and SUMIF/COUNTIF will try to convert those to numbers but, because Excel only works with 15 significant figures in numeric data, you get a lot more matches for each item. You could use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(DATA!$A$3:$A$7996=A3),DATA!$B$3:$B$7996)
```

instead.

Comment: Than @rory I did not know that 15 limit.  Thanks for your post.  I will check and then tag this post as answer

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to the problem mentioned by @Rory is to force `SUMIF` to see that value as text:  (***IF** your keys are all the same length*)

```
=SUMIF(DATA!A:A,'SUM IF'!A3&"*",DATA!B:B)
```

or

```
=SUMIF(DATA!A:A,"*"&'SUM IF'!A3,DATA!B:B)
```

Comment: your posts are always great.  I am working with excel again.   Thanks for your time.and for sharing your knowledge